# Implementation for nested query parameter on API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am working on AWS Lambda function in Python via Amazon AWS Chalice (Python Serverless microframework). I am trying to find out a way to implement nested query parameters on GET Request via AWS API Gateway which triggers the lambda which i am working on.

Example Request: Something like - GET /save?

```
logstring[]=usrid&logstring[]=passed
```

As per reference I found from amazon below, it says that it does not support nested query param

[API Gateway Http Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/making-http-requests/)

The workaround described here is still compel me to change input structure for the request.

My goal is to migrate the Web API service to server less API via lambda without any input changes to the request. I want to keep the exact input query parameter structure for API and don't want to modify it as many of our clients are still using it with existing input query param structure.

Anyone helping me out if there would some way to do it.

Comment: The communication of your Internet card is not a readable article. A Get action has a minimum content requirement. Although it seems simple, it is difficult to write the service to secure it. no APIs can work as you say, you may use the URL address that is requested inside.

Comment: @Vedank, have you tried sending a request with that query parameter and see what your Lambda receives? Maybe you'll still be able to receive it in your Lambda but you might have to parse it yourself as opposed to API Gateway parsing it for you.

Comment: @dashmug Yes, i tried and lambda receives the parameters but not the way I want. Here logstring[]=usrid&logstring[]=passed sends two times in query string but get only last value inside lambda function i.e logstring[]=passed as it overwrite with value - usrid